# How to get Textview in ListAdapterView Using Position or Id

Tags: android, listview

I am making a project like Student List View. All Students are in the list view. When I click on a student, it appears as present. The issue is that when the I scroll down or change views then the same position showed present. What is the issue in my code?

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data == null)
        return;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case requestcode:
            String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
            try {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
                    InputStream inStream;
                    Workbook wb = null;
                    try {
                        inStream = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
                        wb = new HSSFWorkbook(inStream);
                        inStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        lbl.setText("First "+e.getMessage().toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    XlsxCon dbAdapter = new XlsxCon(this);
                    Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
                    if (sheet1 == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    dbAdapter.open();
                    dbAdapter.delete();
                    dbAdapter.close();
                    dbAdapter.open();
                    Excel2SQLiteHelper.insertExcelToSqlite(dbAdapter, sheet1);
                    dbAdapter.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                lbl.setText(ex.getMessage().toString() + "Second");
            }
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList = controller
                    .getProducts();
            if (myList.size() != 0) {
                 lv = getListView();
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, myList,
                        R.layout.v, new String[]{Company, Product,
                        Price},
                        new int[]{R.id.txtproductcompany, R.id.txtproductname,
                                R.id.txtproductprice});
                setListAdapter(adapter);

            }

    }

}
public class ListClickHandler implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       /// String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

        TextView voter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.voter);

        long x = id;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , x+"ha",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(voter.getText() != "PRESENT") {
            voter.setText(position+"PRESENT");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Vote casted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Already Casted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lvh"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:background="#ffe6e6e6"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:clickable="false">
    <ImageView
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtproductcompany"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:text="NAME"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:textColor="#2e69a3"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtproductname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:text="Father Name"
        android:textColor="#3b343b"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtproductprice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="33100-3449820-1"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:textColor="#e44040"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ali"
        android:id="@+id/voter"
        android:textColor="#82da24"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


 </RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of changing view, change text in your list and call `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Like

```
voter.setText(position+"PRESENT"); \\replace this with followinf=g

//somthing like
myList.get(position) = "PRESENT";
this.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: this is not work for me :(
#Kurnal i m new in android , myList.get(position) this is integer method

Comment: Listview is using your arrayList value to bind to its particular view. So for best practice you just change your value at what position you clicked and try refreshing layout by calling  notifyDataSetChanged(); You are using custome adapter ? ri8 ?